# how to get null while parsing xml with geotools parser

Tags: java, xml-parsing, geotools, xsi

I tried to get null value from my xml file such below

```
  <top:kadastroParselFeature gml:id="KADASTRO_PARSEL.1">
    <top:olcek xsi:nil="true" />
  </top:kadastroParselFeature>
```

but my parser throws such an exception :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parsing failed for kadastroParselFeature: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.geotools.xml.impl.ParseExecutor.visit(ParseExecutor.java:164)
at org.geotools.xml.impl.BindingWalker$BindingExecutionChain.execute(BindingWalker.java:220)
at org.geotools.xml.impl.BindingWalker.walk(BindingWalker.java:186)
at org.geotools.xml.impl.ElementHandlerImpl.endElement(ElementHandlerImpl.java:236)
at org.geotools.xml.impl.ParserHandler.endElement(ParserHandler.java:719)
```

My parser configuration like this :

```
   org.geotools.xml.Configuration configuration = new org.geotools.gml2.GMLConfiguration();

   org.geotools.xml.Parser parser = new org.geotools.xml.Parser( configuration );

   parser.setFailOnValidationError(false);

   HashMap<Object, Object> parsedMap = (HashMap<Object, Object>) parser.parse( isx);
```

if I remove `xsi:nill="true"` from element it returns ""(empty string) but i need null .

there is a usage of my parser at http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/xml/geometry.html

Comment: can turn up the logging level, failing that have a look at the problem in a debigger to see what is happening?

Comment: hi iant ı found the problem I use gml2 while parsing this cause the problem. When ı use gml3 version it not give error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for my work the problem at my gml writer version if i changed the version from gml2 to gml3 the problem not seen. and ı changed my parser config. like this

```
       org.geotools.xml.Configuration configuration = new org.geotools.gml3.ApplicationSchemaConfiguration("sampleURL", "sample.xsd");


       org.geotools.xml.Parser parser = new org.geotools.xml.Parser( configuration );
```